# functor and function at priority_queue and sort of C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, functor

I try to understand use of functor and function at C++

Please see the code below

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool mySort(int a, int b){
    if(a > b) return true;
    return false;
}

class myClass{

public:
    bool operator()(int a, int b){
        if(a>b) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main(){

    //(1) priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> aa;
    //(2) priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>()> bb;
    //(3) priority_queue<int, vector<int>, myClass> cc;
    //(4) priority_queue<int, vector<int>, mySort> dd;

    vector<int> check={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    //(a) sort(check.begin(), check.end(), mySort);
    //(b) sort(check.begin(), check.end(), myClass);
    //(c) sort(check.begin(), check.end(), myClass());


    return 0;
}
```

I found only (1),(3) and (a),(c) works.

What is the difference between function and functor when using sort and priority_queue?

I know functor can maintain its state but, this information is not related in this case.

I also check [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) but fail to understand it.

Could you help me?

Comment: Not a bug, but `return a > b;` is all you need in those functions.

Comment: `mySort` doesn't **sort**, but **compare**.

Comment: `greater<int>` is a type, `greater<int>()` is a function type (function taking no parameters returning a `greater<int>`) or an instance depending of context. So the difference are mainly the same as between `int`, `int()`, 42.

Comment: Tip: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables.

Comment: @Jarod42 I understand your words! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @tadman your words is so helpful because I'm newbie. Thank you so much!

Comment: @molbdnilo You're right. it clarify and simplify my codes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate a `priority_queue`, the third argument must be a type.
`greater<int>` and `myClass` are types; `greater<int>()` and `mySort` are not.
If you create a default `priority_queue`, it will default-initialise an ordering of the indicated type.

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> aa;
```

is equivalent to

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> aa(greater<int>());
```

and

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, myClass> cc;
```

is equivalent to

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, myClass> cc(myClass());
```

When you call `sort`, you give it a callable object as the third argument, and the template arguments are deduced from the function arguments.
`mySort` and `myClass()` are callable objects; their types are `bool(int,int)` and `myClass`, respectively, and these types become the template arguments.
`myClass` is a type and can't be used as a function argument.

```
sort(check.begin(), check.end(), mySort);
```

is equivalent to

```
sort<vector<int>::iterator, bool(int,int)>(check.begin(), check.end(), mySort);
```

and

```
sort(check.begin(), check.end(), myClass());
```

is equivalent to

```
sort<vector<int>::iterator, myClass>(check.begin(), check.end(), myClass());
```

Comment: I totally understand it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: `greater<int>()` might be a (function) type, and `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> aa(greater<int>());` would be most vexing parse too.

Comment: `mySort` decays to pointer, so `bool (*) (int, int)`.